# Azure Data Factory - Webhook Logic App timeout when loading a SharePoint List with it

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-data-factory

I have an Azure Data Factory pipeline, where parameters are given for a specific Microsoft SharePoint List: its URL and the list name. However, when debugging the pipeline, the Logic App (Webhook activity) timeouts and seems not to find the SharePoint list at all. It finds other SharePoint lists very well but not this one specific one, even though we have double checked the URL and List name.

The Logic App includes the GetItems activity which gets the site address (URL) and the SharePoint List name (SharePointSite and SharePointFolder) as parameters and finds the list contents with the help of those.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out **the SharePoint list in question had a "/" (slash) in its name. When we removed the slash, the Logic App was able to find the list after all!**